# Lua and OOP (What am I doing wrong?)

Tags: lua

Im learning to code lua and believe I have come quite far and recently picked up the LOVE2D engine. Ive decided to try some OOP to sort out my coding however all efforts seem to fail with the error

> main.lua:31: Attempt to call field "Draw"(nil value)

```
function love.load()
Unicorn = {
    name = "Default",
    breedname = "Default Class of a unicorn",
    description = "Quite a default Unicorn",
    imgclass = love.graphics.newImage("UnicornA.gif"),
    x = 20,
    y = 20,
    height = 0,
    width= 0,
    age = 0,
    maxage = 20,
    health = 100
    }
function Unicorn.Draw(self)
    love.graphics.draw(self.imgclass, self.x, self.y)
end
function Unicorn:new(o)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self._index = self
    return o
end
alfred = Unicorn:new()
alfred.x = 50
harry = Unicorn:new()
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.print("Unicorn Farm Simulator 2014", 0, 0)
    alfred.Draw(alfred)
    harry.Draw(harry)
end
```

To clear things up love.draw is a callback and so is love.load. I am creating the class Unicorn with a Draw function and a New function, the new function creates an Instantation of the Class ( Am i right with that vocabulary?)

Sorry about using full capital acronym for the language, I just presumed it stood for something!

Comment: Please don't confuse between [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) and [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/lua). Both languages are different. "Lua" is a name, and means "Moon" in Portugese. Please **do not write** it as _"LUA"_, which is both ugly and confusing, because then it becomes an acronym with [different meanings](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/lua) for different people.

Comment: Try `self.__index` instead of `self._index`

Comment: Egor thank you so much, I must have overlooked the double underscore!

Comment: Remember that Lua is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `self._index = self` to `self.__index = self`, because `_index` is nonsense here.

You could read more about OO in Lua in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058878/lua-object-oriented-programming-i-dont-understand-how-to-new-up-an-instance-o/21062734#21062734) I have made.

**Bonus:**

1. Make `Unicorn.Draw(self)` to `Unicorn:Draw()`, to get rid of `self`. And use it in this way

   ```
   alfred:Draw()
   harry:Draw()
   ```
2. Use `local` as possible as it can be. Because `local` is faster and friendly to memory usage.